# Complex Function Singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I have to provide a function $f(z)$ which is analytic in **C** except for (i) at a single pole at $z = 3$, (ii) a removable singularity at $z=0$ and (iii) an essential singularity at $z=-1$.

I've defined $f(z) = f_i +f_{ii} + f_{iii}$.

Where $f_{i}(z) = \frac{z+1}{z+3}$, $f_{ii}(z) = \frac{1}{z}$, and $f_{iii}(z) = sin\left(\frac{7}{z+1}\right)$.

I have referred to [this site](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c612.html).

Comment: What makes you think that $\frac{1}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$?

Comment: This $f$ has a pole at $z=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $$f(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-3} +\frac{\sin z}{z}+e^{\frac{1}{z+1}}.$$

Comment: I was reading [this wikipedia document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) when you posted an answer.

Comment: Why did you also change my last term of my proposed equation?

Comment: Your last one is fine.